# Как настроить, что б любой роут вёл на один контроллер и действие на ASP:NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Как сделать, что б все запросы вели на один контроллер и экшен (за исключением статики и api, которые я укажу)? Так как роутинг у меня фактичеки делает JavaScript на клиенте- я хочу выводить по любому запросу один и тот же View

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{*catchall}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    );
```

Попробуй так: `"{*catchall}"` (именно со звездочкой) позволит перехватить запрос с любым количеством сегментов, в `defaults` пропишешь те значения, которые тебе необходимы. Поскольку роут довольно общий - лучше ставить его самым последним

Answer (score -1):

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "Home/Index/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

и для Api

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "API Default",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```